# How to turn Rational to Real in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have some issue here which I don't know how to solve in a good way. For example, I want to use `BaseForm[1/3, 3]`. However, this does not do what I intended unless I input `BaseForm[1/3.,3]`. Given the data in Rational form, how to turn it to Real? I tried with `Apply`, it does not work. (Strange enough, uh? To me, Apply can always be used to change header.)

To this specific problem, I could have done something like `BaseForm[1/3*1.,3]`, but it really isn't very nice.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Using `Apply` works; it changes the head of the expression. `Real@@Rational[1,3] == Real[1,3]` -- but what is `Real[1,3]` mean? You could just use `N@Rational[1, 3]`...

Comment: @Simon: oh, I see. Just forgot to see the nonsensical `Real[1,3]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BaseForm` takes a rational in base 10 to a rational in what ever base you want... so it does what you expect.

```
In[1]:= BaseForm[1/3,3]
Out[1]//BaseForm= Subscript[1, 3]/Subscript[10, 3]
```

And as you pointed out, giving it a Real number can be done like:

```
In[2]:= BaseForm[1/3.,3]
Out[2]//BaseForm= Subscript[0.1, 3]
```

The safest way to change things would be to define your own `baseForm` which is the same as `BaseForm` except for when it's given rational numbers:

```
baseForm[r_Rational,b_]:=BaseForm[N[r],b]
```

Then

```
In[3]:= baseForm[1/3,3]
Out[3]//BaseForm= Subscript[0.1, 3]
```

---

The less safe way (because you don't know what else it might break) is to redefine `BaseForm`

```
Unprotect[BaseForm];
BaseForm[r_Rational, b_] := BaseForm[N[r], b]
Protect[BaseForm];
```

and then use as normal.

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing the subtlety of your request, but if you always want a real-number output, why not merely use `N`?

```
BaseForm[N[1/3], 3]
```

```
(*  Out=  0.13  *)
```